# AndAllowWhileIdle alarms not working when wifi and mobile data off

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have created a broadcast receiver to re schedule alarm.

```
public class EventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    PowerManager.WakeLock screenWakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {

        Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "received event");


        if (screenWakeLock == null) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            screenWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                "ScreenLock tag from AlarmListener");
            screenWakeLock.acquire();
        }

        //do some work

        Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, EventReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context.getApplicationContext(), Constants.REQUEST_CODE, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);

        if (screenWakeLock != null){
            screenWakeLock.release();
        }


    }
```

I checked it for few hours in my phone(Huawei 9s) and observed that,

- **when wifi or data is on** : alarm works perfectly in doze mode
- **both are off** : alarm not working

Got same results for **setAndAllowWhileIdle** method too.
Want some help to identify root cause and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, many Android device manufacturers limit background operations and alarms are one of them. I don't know why you only limit it when wifi and data are turned off. I can advise you not to use PowerManager.WakeLock but to use goAsync if you have important work to do in the broadcast receiver (for example downloading data from the server). In addition, the user must deactivate the energy saving for your app (for android versions above 12 there is an extra permission (https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#exact-permission-declare ) and probably other options (depending on the device and android version) to make the alarm trigger.

```
public class EventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {

        Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "received event");

        final PendingResult result = goAsync();
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                //do some work

                Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, EventReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        context.getApplicationContext(), Constants.REQUEST_CODE, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
                result.finish();
            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }

}
```

Here are some tips you can follow for Huawei devices (of course, depending on the Android version or device, some settings may change):

Step 1
From the Android Home, tap on Settings.
Tap Advanced Settings.
Tap Battery Optimization.
Secure Tap Apps.
Activate App Name.

Step 2
From the Android Home, tap on Settings.
Tap Apps.
Advanced Tap.
Select Ignore Battery Optimization.
Choose App Name and ignore.

Step 3
From the Android Home, tap on Settings.
Select the Notifications & Status Bar.
Tap Notification Center and find App Name.
Make sure that allow Notifications and priority view are turned on.

Here you can find other useful information:
https://dontkillmyapp.com